# Easiest method to install Facebook Pixel

Tags: layout, facebook, ecommerce-tracking

Complete coding illiterate here so forgive my incompetence.

Trying to install Facebook Pixel in my store, would simply copy & pasting my pixel code into here work?

[image]

Any help and advice are greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that by pasting the Pixel code Facebook gives you from the `<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->` to the `<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->` would paste the relevant code before the header, and providing you follow the rest of the documentation [here](https://en-gb.facebook.com/business/help/952192354843755) you should be fine. Best of luck. I should note that use the code that Facebook gives you, not the below code I've left this in for other developers to read.

```
<!-- Facebook Pixel Code -->
<script>
!function(f,b,e,v,n,t,s){if(f.fbq)return;n=f.fbq=function(){n.callMethod?
n.callMethod.apply(n,arguments):n.queue.push(arguments)};if(!f._fbq)f._fbq=n;
n.push=n;n.loaded=!0;n.version='2.0';n.queue=[];t=b.createElement(e);t.async=!0;
t.src=v;s=b.getElementsByTagName(e)[0];s.parentNode.insertBefore(t,s)}(window,
document,'script','https://connect.facebook.net/en_US/fbevents.js');
// Insert Your Facebook Pixel ID below. 
fbq('init', 'FB_PIXEL_ID');
fbq('track', 'PageView');
</script>
<!-- Insert Your Facebook Pixel ID below. --> 
<noscript><img height="1" width="1" style="display:none"
src="https://www.facebook.com/tr?id=FB_PIXEL_ID&amp;ev=PageView&amp;noscript=1"
/></noscript>
<!-- End Facebook Pixel Code -->
```

Answer (score 0):

The easiest method is to use a free extension for Magento 2 (officially provided by Facebook)

- Download link here: https://facebook.com/ads/pixel/integration/?integration=magento2
- Learn how to use this extension: https://www.facebook.com/business/help/532749253576163

There are also other methods like manually inserting code or using google tag manager to insert pixel code, **read this tutorial for full guide**: https://magentip.com/add-facebook-pixel-magento-2/